# How to get Magento 2 latest version number available?

Tags: magento2, version

Magento 1 was here:
`http://connect20.magentocommerce.com/community/Mage_All_Latest/releases.xml`

Where is Magento 2?

Comment: Please add your solution as an answer instead of an update to your question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the latest Magento 2 code is published to GitHub (unlike Magento 1), the list of all releases can be found there: https://github.com/magento/magento2/releases

Answer (score 0):

great, if we rely on github releases, then we can create some simple check/variable from:

```
VERSION=$(curl -s https://api.github.com/repos/magento/magento2/releases 2>&1 | head -36 | grep -E 'tag_name|published_at')

echo "${VERSION}"

"tag_name": "2.0.1",
"published_at": "2016-01-20T14:59:42Z",
```

**UPDATE:**
correct way to get the latest version number (cause of magento versioning):

```
VERSION=$(curl -s https://api.github.com/repos/magento/magento2/tags 2>&1 | head -3 | grep -oP '(?<=")\d.*(?=")')
```

Comment: The problem of this approach is not considering the -p1 -p2 versions.

Answer (score 0):

You can get releases at https://github.com/mageplaza/magento-versions

### JSON

Souce: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mageplaza/magento-versions/master/releases/releases.json

```
{
    "2.2.3": {
        "v": "2.2.3",
        "s": "stable",
        "d": "2018-02-27"
    },
    "2.2.2": {
        "v": "2.2.2",
        "s": "stable",
        "d": "2017-12-12"
    },
    "2.2.1": {
        "v": "2.2.1",
        "s": "stable",
        "d": "2017-11-07"
    }
}
```

### XML

Source: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mageplaza/magento-versions/master/releases/releases.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<releases>
   <r>
      <v>2.2.3</v>
      <s>stable</s>
      <d>2018-02-27</d>
   </r>
   <r>
      <v>2.2.2</v>
      <s>stable</s>
      <d>2017-12-12</d>
   </r>
</releases>
```

Comment: why did you spam this here??? why we need to check magento 2 version on different repo, not a magento 2 official repository???

Comment: At Mageplaza, we are using the repo to get the latest version of Magento 2. It is pulling from Github M2 releases daily. It is easy to find and compare with latest version. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer this bash command

```
VERSION_FULL=$(curl --silent "https://api.github.com/repos/magento/magento2/releases/latest" | grep -Po '"tag_name": "\K.*?(?=")')
    
echo $VERSION_FULL
```